# Errors from intoDNS, how to solve them?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I've got following errors and I'm really frustrated, it is about two days struggling to solve the problem, am just making things worse I think!

When I check mydomain in intodns I get the following errors:
What should be the cause??

[image]

- Firewall has allowed port 53
- I've defined NS1,NS2.
- Something seems weird though >--< when I click start link in BIND DNS
  SERVER it refreshes the page and stop link does not appear. If I've
  misconfigured how to uninstall BIND?

**EDIT:**

```
$ttl 38400
domain.ir.  IN  SOA server.domain.ir. a\.b.gmail.com. (
            1337431548
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
domain.ir.  IN  NS  server.domain.ir.
www.domain.ir.  IN  A   XX.59.XX.204
domain.ir.  IN  NS  ns1.domain.ir.
domain.ir.  IN  NS  ns2.domain.ir.
domain.ir.  IN  A   XX.59.XX.204
ns1.domain.ir.  IN  A   XX.59.XX.204
ns2.domain.ir.  IN  A   XX.59.XX.204
```

And named.cnf is as below:

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { localhost; };
    recursion yes;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
```

BIND DNS server start link is: `Start` when I click it I get the below error message:

```
Failed to start BIND : Starting named: Error in named configuration: zone domain.ir/IN: NS 'server.domain.ir' has no address records (A or AAAA) zone domain.ir/IN: not loaded due to errors. _default/domain.ir/IN: bad zone [FAILED]
```

when I deleted the domain.ir zone and clicked `Start` then page got refreshed without any changes! ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
zone domain.ir/IN: NS 'server.domain.ir' has no address records (A or AAAA)
```

Bind is not loading your zone because it is invalid.

```
domain.ir.  IN  NS  server.domain.ir.
```

This nameserver (i.e. server.domain.ir) doesn't have an IP address associated with it (i.e. there is no A record). Make sure that all nameservers have both an NS record and an A record. Since you've already got ns1 and ns2 I'm guessing that server.domain.ir isn't supposed to be a nameserver, so just remove this line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add NS records into your zone file:

```
whatever.com    IN   NS ns1.whatever.com.
whatever.com    IN   NS ns2.whatever.com.
```

If you are using a web based control panel the NS records are a specific record type. Sometimes on web-based DNS systems it is in the "Advanced" or "SOA" administration.

There's a good example here: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/ns.html

Comment: See the edit part.

Comment: I think you will be fine if you remove this line: domain.ir.  IN  NS  server.domain.ir.